# Swift Protocol Function: returning the same type of conforming class

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I want to know if something java-like (or c++) can be done in Swift:

I have a protocol:

```
protocol Prot1 {
   func returnMyself() -> Prot1
}
```

And a class conforms the protocol `Prot1`.
Can I force the return type of the function `returnMyself()` to be the same type of the class like below?

```
class MyClass: Prot1 {
   public func returnMyself() -> MyClass {
      return self
   }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Just use `Self` into your protocol

```
protocol Prot1 {
   func returnMyself() -> Prot1
}
```

### Here's an example

```
protocol Animal {
    func mySelf() -> Self
}

class Feline: Animal {
    func mySelf() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}

class Cat: Feline { }

Feline().mySelf() // Feline
Cat().mySelf() // Cat
```

### About protocol extensions

You can also use Self inside a protocol extension like this

```
protocol Animal {}

extension Animal {
    func mySelf() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}
```

Now a class just need to conform to Animal like this

```
class Feline: Animal { }
class Cat: Feline { }
class Dog: Animal {}
```

and automatically gets the method

```
Feline().mySelf() // Feline
Cat().mySelf() // Cat
Dog().mySelf() // Dog
```

### Update

```
protocol ReadableInterval { }

class Interval: ReadableInterval { }

protocol ReadableEvent {
    associatedtype IntervalType: ReadableInterval
    func getInterval() -> IntervalType
}

class Event: ReadableEvent {
    typealias IntervalType = Interval
    func getInterval() -> Interval {
        return Interval()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I would've used an associated type for this. This is much nicer.

Comment: @AMomchilov: Thanks!

Comment: I like this approach, but was an example of specializing, in the case i have MyClass2 witch confirms the Prot1 too, can i specialize the member func returnMyself() -> MyClass2 from MyClass?

Comment: @4bottiglie: Sure! You can implement the method in `MyClass2` as well. Remember adding the `override` keyword and returning `MyClass2`.

Comment: I understand that, but my question was if there is a way to implement: func returnMyself() -> MyClass2 in MyClass not in MyClass2 ; don't ask my why i would, this will clear my doubt in specializing.

Comment: @4bottiglie In the code of your question you asked how to return `MyClass` from `MyClass`. Now you want to return `MyClass2` from `MyClass`? So you want to declare a method that always return `MyClass2`?

Comment: I am sorry for the first question. I did not think there where many ways to specialize a return type ( i came from java ) . If i have a protocol ( ex: MyProt ) that has a method witch returns an other protocol ( func getProt() -> ProtR1 ). Lets say MyClass confirms MyProt and MyClassR confirms ProtR1. Can i ovveride the mothod in MyClass like :  func getProt() -> MyClassR ?

Comment: @4bottiglie: what?!?! :D Give me the Java code so I can understand what you need.

Comment: @4bottiglie: let me know if the updated section does solve your problem

Comment: I seen the update, getInterval() from ReadableEvent should return ReadableInterval not Interval, because in implementations of ReadableEvent i want to return other types of Interval that are not necessary subclasses of Interval

Answer (score 3):

```
protocol Prot1
{
    associatedtype T
    func returnMyself() -> T
}

class MyClass : Prot1
{
    typealias T = MyClass
    func returnMyself() -> T
    {
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your style; the associated type T will be restricted for the subclasses   of Prot1 when you do: typealias T = MyClass? If not it's a way to restrict it?

Comment: once you do `typealias T = MyClass` it will be restricted to `MyClass`. Meaning that subclasses would also have to implement `func returnMyself() -> MyClass`